# Convert Year, Julien, & Time to POSIXct from multiple columns quickly and efficiently in base R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a lot of large dataframes (+500,000 rows) that come to me with datetime information stored across multiple columns. Instead of a MM/DD/YYYY format it has Year in one column, Julien calendar day in the next, and time in a third. The data is structured like this:

```
df<-data.frame(YEAR = sample(2000:2020,10000, replace=T), 
           JULIEN = sample(1:365,10000,replace=T),
           Time = sample(0:59,10000,replace = T),
           dataVar1 = runif(10000,1.0,10.0),
           dataVar2 = runif(10000,20.0,100.0))
```

So far I have been getting by with this:

```
timeR<-vector()
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
currentTime<-paste(as.Date(df$JULIEN[i], origin=paste(df$YEAR[i]-1,"-12-31", sep = "")),formatC(df$Time[i], width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"))
timeR<-c(timeR,currentTime)
}
df<-cbind(timeR,df[, ! names(df) %in% c("YEAR","JULIEN","Time")])
df$timeR<-as.POSIXct(df$timeR,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H%M", tz = "EST")
rm(timeR,i,currentTime)
```

but it takes a hefty amount of time. Any ideas on how I could make this run quicker? Thank you.

Comment: You can use paste the year, Julien day and time together  and use the %j format specifier: For example just the year and day:  `as.Data(paste(df$YEAR, df$JULIEN), "%Y %j")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` and `as.Date` are vectorized

```
v1 <- as.Date(df$JULIEN, origin = paste0(df$YEAR-1,"-12-31"))
currentTime <- paste(v1, formatC(df$Time, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time({
 timeR<-vector()
 for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  currentTime<-paste(as.Date(df$JULIEN[i], origin=paste(df$YEAR[i]-1,"-12-31", sep = "")),formatC(df$Time[i], width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"))
  timeR<-c(timeR,currentTime)
 }})
#   user  system elapsed #
#  1.300   0.061   1.366 

system.time({
 v1 <- as.Date(df$JULIEN, origin = paste0(df$YEAR-1,"-12-31"))
 currentTime <- paste(v1, formatC(df$Time, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0"))
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.076   0.004   0.080
```